# I denied watchman access/permission to my desktop. How can I now allow it again?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, watchman

I'm developing a React Native app. I keep my workspace on my desktop. Earlier a window came up asking me if I wanted to grant permission for watchman to watch my desktop. I accidentally clicked deny.

I'm not knowledgable enough in this area. How can I give watchman permissions to monitor files on my desktop again? Where is the config file and how must I change it to grant permissions.

I have already tried to uninstall and reinstall it with homebrew....This didn't fix anything.

**Edit**: Below you see that I was able to find it and grant permission again. But why now, do I have multiple watchman entries here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `System Preferences` -> `Security & Privacy` -> `Privacy` tab -> scroll down and click `Full Disk Access`, and then check `Watchman`

Comment: thank you. I did try that. I must not have seen watchman sitting there...I brushed passed it. However, I can grant it full disk access but I decided to give it access to the desktop instead.....But for some reason, it's listed multiple times. Look at my edit img. What should I do now?

Comment: @JoMomma first time seeing it like that, have you tried uninstalling it with brew?

Comment: yes, I think my Mac is possessed. Where does the binary live? Should I try to uninstall it with terminal?

Comment: @JoMomma try running `which watchman` and it should tell you where the binary files are, usually in `usr/bin/watchman`. This might be a better question for https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yeah, it's there but I only see one copy....strange. Perhaps an Apple bug. That's certainly not unheard of lol. I will look further into this. Thanks for your help